# Rails - what is the correct syntax for adding current url to Facebook comments div href?

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've tried every variation I can think of to add the current url path to the href in the facebook comments div. Why doesn't this work?

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%= #{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath} %>" data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>
```

I've also tried this but the end of the ruby injection code seems to end the div this way:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href=<%= "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}" %> data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use a content_tag which converted the original facebook comments div:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>
```

into this:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, nil, :class => 'fb-comments', "data-href" => "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}", "data-width" => '470', "data-num-posts" => "2"  ) %>
```

Comment: hey no problem railsy, anytime

Answer (score 2):

Posting another way in case someone needed it, you were close in the first attempt, no need for the #{} since it is already inside the <%= %>

This worked for me:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%= request.protocol + request.host_with_port + request.fullpath %>" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

However i faced a small issue using this method to retrieve `current_url` since any params in the Url will affect where the comment is attached

e.g `http://localhost:3000/users/1?locale=en` will store different comments than `http://localhsot:3000/users/1?locale=ar` Which is not what i wanted!!

So, i found that using `request.path` instead of `full_path` solves this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%= request.protocol + request.host_with_port + request.path %>" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```